# Use html files from another project in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I know that I can use normal html files in ASP.NET MVC; however I have a situation where several (above 20) html files are needed for static display. This is fine and good, but I really don't want it cluttering the MVC project since none of them will have controller actions.

Is there any way to load up a second project and use static html files from it, within ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know my answer is not directly related to your question as you are asking how to access HTML pages from a second project.  But an alternate would be to place the html files in your content directory.  This way you could catalog your static html pages

For Instance:

```
MVC Directory Structure
   Content
     images
       logo.png
     script
       utility.js
     staticHtml
       static.html
       static2.html
   Model
   Views
```

Comment: Yeah, I can do that. It works fine; I was just hoping to find something that my OCD could actually live with. I did it for another project and it worked, but it's such a hassle to manage. Ideally I'd like to just set up another project in Visual Studio and be able to manage the html/aspx files in there, and it publish with the MVC project as a merged directory.